# if custom post type exist

Tags: posts, customization, function-exists

I want to test if custom post  type `mobile` exist. I used if custom post type exist in the loop, but it doesn't work. Any suggestion why my code is not working

```
<?php /* The loop */ ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>...

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<? if( post_type_exists( 'mobiles' ) ) {  echo 'The Products post type   exists';} ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

<?pp echo 'The post type is: '. get_post_type( get_the_ID() ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I don't see any code. Please update your question..

Comment: look up it works now help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typed "mobiles" when you said you wanted to check for post type "mobile". So simply remove the s ;).

```
<? if( post_type_exists( 'mobiles' ) ) {  echo 'The Products post type   exists';} ?>
```

Should be:

```
<? if( post_type_exists( 'mobile' ) ) {  echo 'The Mobile post type   exists';} ?>
```

If it's still not working, triple check if you succesfully registered a post type named "mobile".

Comment: I correct this but it still the same error and no thing happen

Comment: Never use php short tags. Use proper php tags ( `<?php ?>` ). Shorttags are not enableb by all hosts by default